# JSONPath expression for filtering on multiple levels

Tags: json, filter, jsonpath

After tinkering with the [Heroku app](http://jsonpath.herokuapp.com/?path=$..book%5B?(@.author%20=~%20/.*REES/i%20%7C%7C%20@.price%20%3E%2010)%5D), I am unable to find a JSONPath expression for the below JSON object that allows me to filter on both

```
Log.Transaction.BusinessUnit.Country
```

and

```
Log.Transaction.InventoryControlTransaction.InventoryAdjustment.ItemCounts[*].Quantity
```

Does JSONPath support filtering on multiple paths where each path is at a different level in the JSON structure? If so, what is the expression that I should be using?

```
{
   "Log":{
      "Transaction":{
         "BusinessUnit":{
            "Brand":"Acme",
            "UnitID":"1234",
            "LocationCode":"1234",
            "Country":"USA",
            "LocationType":"Store"
         },
         "BeginDateTime":"2016-07-28T07:30:00.333",
         "InventoryControlTransaction":{
            "InventoryAdjustment":{
               "Reason":"Update",
               "ItemCounts":[
                  {
                     "Item":{
                        "ID":"00000000"
                     },
                     "Quantity":{
                        "Quantity":0,
                        "Type":"Foo"
                     }
                  }
               ]
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

EDIT: Changed "Transactions" field to "Log" for clarity

Comment: Are you sure the node "Transactions" is a JSONObject ? Would it not a JSONArray ?

Comment: yeah, I'm sure that "Transactions" is a JSONObject. I changed the node to "Log" for clarity.

Comment: I have a similar need.  Any luck yet?